# Difference Observable wait and setTimeout for rerendering view template in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs6, angular2-observables

I have local storage for the sort data which can take a while:

```
private store: IBacktest[] = [];

public setStore(content: string): Observable<void> {
    return new Observable<void>((observer) => {
            this.store = content
                .trim()
                .split('\n')
                .map(item => toTestCase(item))
                .sort((a, b) => b.profitToDropDown - a.profitToDropDown);
            observer.next();
            observer.complete();
        }
    );
}
```

Amount of elements 5000 - 10000 and it get 10 - 30 seconds because of `toTestCase`, not a cheap operation. And I want to render loader a more user-friendly interface:

```
this.isLoader = true;
this.backtestService
    .setStore(content)
    .pipe(finalize(() => {
        this.isLoader = false;
    }))
    .subscribe(() => {...});
```

And `<app-loading-overlay *ngIf="isLoader"></app-loading-overlay>` in template.

But when `isLoader = true` and I can see it in debug mode loading-overlay not rendering.

But when I try to test its logic with `setTimeout()` like this: `setTimeout(() => { this.isLoader = false; }, 100000)` all work properly and loader is visible.

What is the problem with my observable use and how to fix it without redundant wrappers like `setTimeout()` or something similar crutches?

Comment: Does the code this.isLoader = false get called? Does it stop there if you put a breakpoint?

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi on the breakpoints `isLoader` have the right values but template no react on changes.

Comment: Perfect. I have another question. Are you using the OnPush strategy? You can see it in the component's decorator.

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi what are You mean about OnPush strategy? In my components decorator only `@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})`

Comment: Usually if Angular doesn't update the view is because of this strategy. But this is not the case. Last thing I have in mind right now is to try to wrap the code inside the function that does the logic in an ngZone.runoutsideangular function: https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi `ngZone.runoutsideangular` the function takes a surprisingly good performance but issue with doesn't update the view not resolve, only setTimeout wrapper solve it(

Comment: I've done an example in local and it works perfectly. If you try to comment the logic in the service (this.store = ....) does it works?

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi this repo on git method `load()`  https://github.com/triodjangopiter/backtest-converter/blob/filter_item/src/app/modules/converter/components/form/form.component.ts and problem service https://github.com/triodjangopiter/backtest-converter/blob/filter_item/src/app/modules/converter/services/store.service.ts

Comment: Thank you Pavel, I'll look into it when I'm home later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `isLoader` is not updating his value in the DOM.

Let's try using `get/set` that we know they will update they value.

```
private _isLoader: boolean = false;
public get isLoader() {
   return this._isLoader;
}
public set isLoader(value: boolean) {
   this._isLoader = value;
}
callsetStore(): {
   this.isLoader = true;
   this.backtestService
    .setStore(content)
    .pipe(finalize(() => {
        this.isLoader = false;
    }))
    .subscribe(() => {...});
}
```

Then in the html:

```
<app-loading-overlay *ngIf="isLoader"></app-loading-overlay>
```

With that, I think it should work know. Try it and if it doesn't work we will try another approach.

Comment: `isProcess` and `isLoader` this mistake of question description I fix it. Unfortunately getter and setter not change anything.

Comment: Thanks for updated the question. I realize that I forget to set ```isLoader = true``` before you call ```this.backtestService.setStore(content)```. 
I have just updated my answer try it now.

Comment: oh this not a problem I catch your idea about get/set

Comment: Does it work? Because of not we can use Observable and the async pipe in the *ngIf

Comment: no, unfortunately, reason not into the directive. I stay link on the source in the comment bellow of the question, this git repo with full code.

Answer (score 1):

I think You need to call `ngZone.run` into your callback function of `ngZone.runOutsideAngular` please have a llok at the screenshot and you can check it from here https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#runOutsideAngular[image]